# 2 Divs Float Right - Not in a Right Order

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs, Green and Red.  Green has to appear right on the left of Red and Red has to sit all the way to the right.  I try to apply float right to these two divs, the result is green goes all the way to the right and Red appears right on the left of Red.

Any Idea?  Here is [LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/7nJp9/25/)

Demo

```css
.three {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  float: left;
  height: 45px
}
.red {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
.green {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Problem solved - switch the order in the markup: http://jsfiddle.net/7nJp9/26/

Comment: @PayerAhammed I think it is not the problem with CSS, DOM order matters.

Comment: @abcid d: I have updated my answer and it's working like you want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all the `floats` and apply display property value of `inline-block` to `.green` and `.red,` that way the elements will stay side by side while maintaining their positions. You don't need to swap the elements. see it working!

**Note:** You must add `text-align: right` to the parent element, which is `.three`

```css
.three {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  float: right;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: right;
}
.red {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
   margin-right: 0!important;

}
.green {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
 
}

.green, .red {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
 

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="three">
    
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

**Note:** You must add `text-align: right` to the parent element, which is .three

Comment: Thank you very much all brothers for your help!  It works now.

Comment: However, right now Green and Red are the right order, but Red has to be all the way to the right.  Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thank you very much Sleek Geek! adjust the width would work, but the width of these don't match with the other elements from entire app.  Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change the order in your HTML markup, thus the red aligns first to the right and then green aligns with respect to the width occupied by green.

```css
.three {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  float: left;
  height: 45px
}
.red {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
.green {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="three">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Negative Margins**

You can use negative margins to get the placement that you need without changing the order of the HTML elements.

First, to the `.green` element, add a right margin equal to the width of the `.red` element.

Second, to the `.red` element, add a right margin with a negative value of the total width of the `.green` and the `.red` elements.

The right margin on the `.green` provides a space for the `.red` element and the negative right margin on the `.red` pulls it back in line with the `.green` element.

```css
.three {
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  float: left;
  height: 45px
}
.red {
  width: 60%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -80%; /* - (width of red + width of green) */
}
.green {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: green;
  height: 40px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 60%; /* width of red */
}
```

```html
<div class="three">
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Simple code to understand it better:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="red">
        <ul>
            <li>abc </li>
            <li>def</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button class="drop">
            ABC</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the Css style is to add 2 divs with right float:

```
.red {
    background-color: red;
    float:left;}

.abc {
    float: right;
}

.red ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.red ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 40px;
}

.button-wrapper {
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;

}

.red::after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";

}
```